# Simple real analysis question - inf and sup

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

This problem looks fairly simple. I just have a question as to what is being asked specifically. The question says to find the infimum and supremum of the set

A=$\{a+a^{-1}:a\in \mathbb{Q}, a>0\}$.

However, it does not specify if the additive or multiplicative inverse is to be used. Any thoughts on which one I should be considering?

Comment: Multiplicative. Otherwise it would say $-a$.

Comment: Also, if it was additive, then $a+a^{-1} = 0$, and the set would only contain one element.